# fetching specific data from core data database and displaying in UITableView

Tags: ios, core-data

I currently have a table view that displays all the contents of the database Entity: ExData.

ExData has an attribute tag of string type.

What my problem is that i would like to display the contents of the ExData in the table view but only the entries that have a tag set of 2 for example.

The tag is to be sent from the previous view controller but this can be sorted out later as firstly i would just like to hard code only one tag value entries being displayed

ExDatasArray is a mutable Array.

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ExData"];

self.ExdatasArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Above is how the data from ExData is being fetched...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch specific data, you add a *predicate* to the fetch request:

```
NSString *theTag = ...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", theTag];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Remark: If you are displaying the result set in a table view, you might also consider to
use a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to limit the results of the fetchRequest.  Use an NSPredicate to specify the query and if desired an NSSortDescriptor to sort it.  Below I assume that your tag attribute is named tag, and that searchTagValue has been set appropriately.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ExData"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", searchTagValue];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tag" ascending:YES]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!result) {
    // handle error
}
else {
    self.ExdatasArray = [results mutableCopy];
}
```